# write to a file after piping output from tail -f through to grep

Tags: linux, unix, grep, tail, centos5

I'm looking to write to a file after piping output from tail -f through to grep.
Say,write to a file "temp" for all lines with "Playing:" within in error_log "FreeSwitch.log".

```
 tail -f "/var/lof/freeswitch/freeswitch.log" | grep "Playing:" > temp
```

but not working ! It is a centos 5.5

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you have an issue with buffering? See [BashFAQ: What is buffering](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009)?

You could e.g. try:

```
tail -f /var/lof/freeswitch/freeswitch.log | grep --line-buffered "Playing:" > temp
```

Comment: Works for me and fixes what the original question is trying to do. This answer should be marked as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

```
-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
              output appended data as the file grows;
```

It scans the file as it grows.  And it is a process with an interval. You can only interrupt it.

Use parameter:

```
-c, --bytes=K
              output the last K bytes; alternatively, use -c +K to output bytes starting with the Kth of each file
```

or

```
-n, --lines=K
              output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth
```

EDIT:  as bmk said:

```
grep --line-buffered
```

think it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Did you put the file name after the `>`?

```
tail -f /var/lof/freeswitch/freeswitch.log | grep "Playing:" > temp
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.

here is my code to insert into mysql with the word "error":

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log | \
grep -E --line-buffered "error" | \
while read line; do \
#echo -e "MY LINE: ${line}"; done
echo "INSERT INTO logs (logid,date,log) VALUES (NULL, NOW(), '${line}');" | mysql -uUSERDB -pPASSDB DBNAME; done
```